# Drop Down List Giving Incorrect Values

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have followed the following tutorial for my project:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h_ViuyVs4AE

The issue that I have is that when I click an item in the first drop down box, it does not give the correct values in the second box, it only gives one value and it is incorrect. It should display all the Model_Name's(Vehicle_Model table) that are for each Make_Name(Vehicle_Make table).

Index.cshtml code:

```
@model GoogleMap.Models.MyPageViewModel

<script>
    $(function () {
        $("#ContID").change(function () {
            $.get("/Map/GetModById", { MID: $("#ContID").val() }, function (data) {
                var $list = $("#St");
                $list.empty();
                $.each(data, function() {
                    $("<option />")
                        .val(this.Model_ID)
                        .text(this.Model_Name)
                        .appendTo($list);
                });
            })
        });
    });
</script>

@Html.DropDownListFor(p => p.SelectedMake_Id, ViewBag.Vehicle_Make as SelectList, "Select Vehicle Make", new { id = "ContID" })
```

MapController.cs code:

```
public class MapController : Controller
{
    private GoogleMapEntities db = new GoogleMapEntities();
    //Get the select ID???
    int SelectedMake_Id = 0;

    // GET: Map
    public ActionResult Index()
    {    
        GoogleMapEntities GE = new GoogleMapEntities();
        List<Vehicle_Details> vehList = db.Vehicle_Details.ToList();

        GoogleMapViewModel GMviewmodel = new GoogleMapViewModel();
        List<GoogleMapViewModel> GMviewmodelList = new List<GoogleMapViewModel>();

        //Populate the ViewModel
        MyPageViewModel vm = new Models.MyPageViewModel();
        vm.GoogleMapViewModelList = GMviewmodelList;
        vm.SelectedMake_Id = SelectedMake_Id;

        ViewBag.Vehicle_Make = new SelectList(db.Vehicle_Make, "Make_ID", "Make_Name");

        return View(vm);               
    }

    public JsonResult GetModById(int MID)
    {
        db.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
        return Json(db.Vehicle_Model.Where(p => p.Model_ID == MID), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Search(string Location)
    {
        GoogleMapEntities GE = new GoogleMapEntities();
        ////SELECT Make_Name DATA FROM DB1
        // var result = GE.Vehicle_Model.Where(x => x.Model_Name.StartsWith(Location)).ToList();
        var GetVeh = db.GetMapSearch().Where(x => x.Model_Name.StartsWith(Location)).ToList();

        return Json(GetVeh, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
}
```

Vehicle_Make has Make_ID (pk) and Make_Name.

Vehicle_Model has Model_ID (pk) and Model_Name.

Vehicle_Details has Vehicle_ID (pk), Model_ID (fk), Make_ID (fk).

So what needs to happen is when I click a vehicle name(Make_Name), it must display all of it's Model_Name's in the second drop down list.

**EDIT:**
I have made a proc called DropDL which has the query that will display the Model name's with their Model_ID's and Make_ID's.

Query in proc:

```
SELECT          Vehicle_Model.Model_Name, Vehicle_Details.Model_ID, 
                Vehicle_Details.Make_ID
FROM            Vehicle_Make INNER JOIN
                Vehicle_Details ON Vehicle_Make.Make_ID = 
                Vehicle_Details.Make_ID INNER JOIN
                Vehicle_Model ON Vehicle_Details.Model_ID =  
                Vehicle_Model.Model_ID
```

The procedure that I have made(GetMapSearch) which linked 4 tables tables for something else, where it linked all of those tables using ID's and getting specific values from each table, worked well, so I do not understand why I'd need to add Make_ID to the Vehicle_Model table unless the drop down list does require that.

Updated code:

```
    public JsonResult GetModById(int MID)
    {
        db.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
        return Json(db.DropDL().Where(p => p.Model_ID == MID)
        .Select(p => new SelectListItem { Text = p.Model_Name, Value = 
        p.Model_ID.ToString() }).ToList(),
        JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

And Index.cshtml code:

```
@model GoogleMap.Models.MyPageViewModel

@using Mvc.CascadeDropDown

@Html.DropDownListFor(p => p.SelectedMake_Id, ViewBag.Vehicle_Make as         
SelectList, "Select Vehicle Make", new { id = "ContID" })

@Html.CascadingDropDownListFor(
expression: m => m.SelectedModelId,
triggeredByPropertyWithId: "ContID",  //Parent property that trigers 
dropdown data loading
url: Url.Action("GetModById", "Map"),  //Url of action that returns dropdown 
data
ajaxActionParamName: "MID", //Parameter name for the selected parent value 
that url action receives
optionLabel: "Please select a Model", // Option label
disabledWhenParentNotSelected: true, //If true, disables dropdown until 
parent dropdown is selected
htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Also, if I changed the ViewBag to use db.DropDL() instead of db.Vehicle_Make, it gets all of the makes but it brings all of the makes up multiple times.

After making the proc, I am still getting one or two Model_Name's for the Make_Name's and also some makes do not give model names. So it is linking the tables, but not correctly.

**FIXED!**

Okay I have fixed it, but does anyone know how to get it to display the Make_Name in alphabetical order and then Model_Name also in alphabetical order once a make name is clicked? Also, remove duplicate model_name's and show one of each instead ?

Also, how do I get the value from Model_Name, once clicked on, to work with my search:

Right now I have to search by typing, how do I get the clicked value's string (Model_Name) to be searched?

```
   [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Search(string Location)
    {
        GoogleMapEntities GE = new GoogleMapEntities();

        var GetVeh = db.GetMapSearch().Where(x => 
        x.Model_Name.StartsWith(Location)).ToList();

        return Json(GetVeh, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

    }
```

Comment: @StephenMuecke Could you please let me know what changes you made to this post? Plz dont mind, I just want to know how in most of the post edited by someone after few sec of posting.

Comment: @BasantaMatia, Just removed the incorrect [tag:model-view-controller] tag (and you can click on the 'edited xx ago' link to see revisions)

Comment: Oh Ok...Thanks for the reply. I never new that we can check what was the edit info. Thanks :)

Comment: @CaptnA Make_ID should be fk in Vehicle_Model, otherwise how can you filter data. You are doing wrong in GetModById() mtd.

Comment: please have a look from "EDIT"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing p.Model_ID to p.Make_ID

```
public JsonResult GetModById(int MID)
{
    db.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
    return Json(db.DropDL().Where(p => p.Make_ID == MID)
    .Select(p => new SelectListItem { Text = p.Model_Name, Value = 
    p.Model_ID.ToString() }).ToList(),
    JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Comment: Looks like your procedure fixed most of the issues, these fixes should also work with your original code, but the CascadeDropDownHelpers as mentioned by Alex Art is a better choice.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [CascadeDropDownHelpers](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Mvc.CascadeDropDown) library to simplify you case a little bit ( disclaimer: I am the author ) :

1) install the nuget package.

2) add to your model SelectedModelId property:

```
public class MyPageViewModel{

    public string SelectedModelId {get;set;}

    // other properties...
}
```

3) modify GetModById action to return a list of SelectListItems as json

```
public JsonResult GetModById(int MID)
{
    db.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
    return Json(db.Vehicle_Model.Where(p => p.Model_ID == MID)
          .Select(p=>  new SelectListItem {Text = p.Model_Name, Value = p.Model_ID.ToString()}).ToList(), 
    JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

4) modify the view (no script additional scrips required):

```
@model GoogleMap.Models.MyPageViewModel

@Html.DropDownListFor(p => p.SelectedMake_Id, ViewBag.Vehicle_Make as SelectList, "Select Vehicle Make", new { id = "ContID" })

@Html.CascadingDropDownListFor( 
  expression: m => m.SelectedModelId, 
  triggeredByPropertyWithId: "ContID",  //Parent property that trigers dropdown data loading
  url: Url.Action("GetModById", "Map"),  //Url of action that returns dropdown data
  ajaxActionParamName: "MID", //Parameter name for the selected parent value that url action receives
  optionLabel: "Please select a Model", // Option label
  disabledWhenParentNotSelected: true, //If true, disables dropdown until parent dropdown is selected
  htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
```

You can find additional usage examples [here](https://github.com/alexanderar/Mvc.CascadeDropDown)

Comment: Just tried this but it basically does the same as before, loads one value and an incorrect value. Is it because there is no Make_ID in the Vehicle_Model table and it's not matching correctly? If so, how come it does give a result even though it is incorrect? If the issue is Make_ID not existing in the Vehicle_Model table then it shouldn't give any value at all right?

Comment: How do I give the "CascadingDropDownListFor" a name?

Comment: Name is automatically generated by helper the same way it does for original DropDownListFor helper.

Comment: Sorry, I meant an id? I need an ID to be able to use it for the search that I am trying to do. Like how the DropDownList has "ContID", I need an id for the CascadingDropDownList.

Comment: You can modify it through htmlAttributes parameter(the last one):
`htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control", id="yourId" }`